# PHP script executes, outputs HTML to browser, but the browser won't display it

Tags: php, html, apache, browser

I have the following script that runs when a user clicks a link that views all their listings:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['review'])) {
//This page is called when users choose to view all their reviews
//STEP 1: find all the reviews created by this user. 

$userReviews = Reviews::findUserReviews($_SESSION['user_id']);
//STEP 2: run a for each that will spit out a list of each review, with a url indicating the review id selected ?>

<ul>
<?php foreach ($userReviews as $userReview): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $siteURL; ?>/index.php?public=6&amp;profile=5&amp;review=<?php echo $userReview->id; ?>"><?php echo $userReview->street; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php } else {
echo "Test Echo";
}
?>
```

It is accessed from an include on another page, the include works, I do not get a PHP error telling me the file doesn't exist.

Furthermore, the server runs the PHP code and outputs it to the page, but the browser won't show it, i just get a blank area where that file is supposed to display.

When I click on view source though, it shows the HTML is there, and output as a result of the PHP:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.mytesturl.com/index.php?public=6&amp;profile=5&amp;review=34"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm at a loss here, the file is obviously working and outputting correctly, but no browsers will show it?

As a test, I tried adding some random text to the page at the bottom of the script after the final closing ?> tag, and the browser does show that, but not the php produced code, OR the  tag just under the "STEP 2: etc....." comment.

I've changed the file name, I've tried changing the "isset" conditions on the page that calls it, I've even changed this file's permissions as a last resort, to no avail.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Apache version  2.2.22
PHP version 5.3.10

Thanks everyone

Comment: K wow, I just solved on my own.
I made the issue more complicated than it was, it didn't display anything because there was no value being outputted for the <a> tag!
*face palm* 

Thanks anyways everyone.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it when you are able to (or delete the question) to keep the site tidy ;-)

Comment: would it be better to post it as an answer to help others? Also, how do i do that lol

Comment: @DavidMorin just answer like you would any other question, or hit `delete` under the question...

Comment: Thanks guys, just tried to answer and it won't let me b/c my rep score isn't high enough yet.

Comment: @DavidMorin You will have a time limit since you are a fairly new user, towards the bottom of the page there should be a message telling you how long you have to wait before you are able to answer your own question, I think it is two hours, just come back and answer it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no content to show.

Try putting some test content between `<a>` and `</a>`.

In other words, `$userReview->street` appears to be empty and is producing no output. The rest of the markup does not render anything, just as `<p></p>` does not result in anything on the screen.

Comment: Thanks yeah, that was the answer, I actually had figured it out about 20 seconds after I posted it (see comments above). But because I am new it wouldn't let me answer my own question for 8 hours. I won't need to know though thanks for answering!